# iOS crash inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Here's the code, starts from here:

```
[XXNetwork postDataWithPath:path parameters:paras progress:nil success:^(id obj) {
    ...
}failure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    [XXLogger endMark:logID action:^(id<XXTrackObj> trackObj) {
        [trackObj setResultCode:[@(error.code) stringValue]];
        NSString *errString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"errorInfo: %@", error];  // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x134)
        [trackObj setModuleExt:errString];
    }];
}];
```

The program crashes at `NSString *error = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"errorInfo: %@", error];` where I made a comment in the code. I found the `error` object is abnormal when I was debugging.

---

The method in `XXlogger` looks like this:

```
// XXLogger.m
- (void)endMark:(NSString *)trackID action:(void (^)(id<XXTrackObj> trackObj))block {
    XXLogModel *model = [self.trackCache objectForKey:trackID];
    if (block) {
        block(model);
    }
}
```

---

Here are my questions:

1. How and why does the crash happen?
2. Why does the crash not happen at `[trackObj setResultCode:[@(error.code) stringValue]]` for it also uses object `error`?

Any idea would be very appreciated.

----------(Edit 1st)

Here is the code in XXNetwork.m

```
+ (void)postDataWithPath:(NSString *)path 
              parameters:(NSDictionary *)paras 
                progress:(XXProgressBlock)progress 
                 success:(void(^)(id obj))success 
                 failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {
    AFHTTPManager *manager = [self sharedHTTPSessionManager];
    ... 
    // some configurations for manager
    ...
    [manager POST:url parameters:paras progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTsk * task, id responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTsk * task, NSError * error) {
        failure(error);
    }];
}
```

----------(Edit 2nd)

The crash seems to be solved by creating a temporary variable for error. Here is the code:

```
[XXNetwork postDataWithPath:path parameters:paras progress:nil success:^(id obj) {
    ...
}failure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSError *tmpError = error;
    [XXLogger endMark:logID action:^(id<XXTrackObj> trackObj) {
        [trackObj setResultCode:[@(tmpError.code) stringValue]];
        NSString *errString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"errorInfo: %@", tmpError];  // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x134)
        [trackObj setModuleExt:errString];
    }];
}];
```

Now the crash won't happen, but I'm still wondering the real reason and other solutions.

Comment: You're trying to access a released object most likely, or one with a dangling pointer

Comment: Can you show the code of postDataWithPath: method? The part where the error object is created?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I have posted the code of  'post method'. The error is created in AFNetworking.

Comment: @Woodstock Yes, I agree. But I am still wondering why the object is released, isn't it in the scope?

Comment: I might have use `__block NSError *blockError = error;` to be sure that's it's kept in the scope despite the asynchronous following block.